# Python Boolean etc

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment:

> Have you ever noticed a sign like this on an elevator? Have you ever wondered if the people on the elevator were within the rated load?
>   In this problem you will write code that:
>
> - asks the user for the rated load of the elevator
> - starts with the assumption that the elevator is empty
> - asks the user for the weight of the next passenger
> - checks to see if that passenger can get on the elevator
> - if they can, it says so, adds that weight to the current weight on the elevator and continues
> - if that passenger will exceed the weight capacity it says so and then quits.

For Example

[image: example run]

When I run the program now, it continuously prints "Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. " I eventually have to kill it.  Any help is appreciated.  I am sure I am missing something easy.

Code:

```
currentWeight = 0

weightLimit = int(input("What is the rated load of the elevator? "))

newPassengerWeight = int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))

keepGoing=True

while currentWeight<=weightLimit:

    if currentWeight + newPassengerWeight<=weightLimit:
        currentWeight=currentWeight + newPassengerWeight
        print("The person can get on.")
    else:
        keepGoing=False
        print("Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. ")
```

Comment: How can you possibly be getting that error when there's no code actually using `keepGoing`?

Comment: @eyllanesc,==, did you include the int() function for him in the code, I think he is unaware though.....

Comment: @eyllanesc,ignore me, in his first version of question int(), and "Time to quit" not in  else loop, so it should be the OP himeself changed it...

Comment: @eyllanesc, noted, sir, I think I need 1.5k more rep to review the edit.

Comment: @ eyllanesc, thanks sir. Found how to view editing queue just now.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Time to quite` print in the Else block

```
while True:

    if currentWeight + newPassengerWeight<=weightLimit: # If it will become false then execution will come out of while loop
        currentWeight=currentWeight + newPassengerWeight
        print("The person can get on.")
    else:
        keepGoing=False
        print("Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. ")
        break
```

Or there is better way of doing the same thing

```
# Without using keepGoing variable
while (currentWeight + newPassengerWeight) <= weightLimit:
    currentWeight=currentWeight + newPassengerWeight
    print("The person can get on.")

print("Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. ")
```

Comment: It's still printing it continuously. This has me stumped.

Comment: Updated.. Missed to add `break`

Comment: The variable `keepGoing` no longer serves any useful purpose in the first version, either.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suppose you should move keepGoing in the while loop condition to make more sense on this variable.
2. Move "Time to quit" inside else statement, or else it will call every single loop.
3. You need to keep inputing the new passenger weight. So

   ```
   newPassengerWeight = int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))
   ```

   should be included inside the loop.
4. They all should be an integer, so you need

> int(input("What is the rated load of the elevator? "))
>
> int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))

to make them integer.

```
currentWeight = 0

weightLimit = int(input("What is the rated load of the elevator? "))

keepGoing=True

while keepGoing:
    newPassengerWeight = int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))
    currentWeight+= newPassengerWeight
    if currentWeight<=weightLimit:
        print("The person can get on.")
    else:
        keepGoing=False
        print("Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. ")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the condition to exit the loop is incorrect. But, a far bigger problem is that, you are not asking the user to enter the `newPassengerWeight` again. Due to this you will entering the `newPassengerWeight` only once, which is incorrect as per the requirement mentioned by you.

Try the code in the below way:

```
currentWeight = 0   
weightLimit = int(input("What is the rated load of the elevator? "))    
newPassengerWeight = int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))


while (currentWeight + newPassengerWeight)<=weightLimit:
    print("The person can get on.")
    currentWeight += newPassengerWeight
    newPassengerWeight = int(input("What is the weight of the next passenger? "))

print("Time to quit.  This person will exceed the weight limit of the elevator. ")
```

In above code:

- Current Weight is 0 in the beginning and Weight Limit is initialized.
- User enters the New Passenger Weight, if the new passenger exceeds the weight, he cannot enter the lift.
- If the new passenger doesnt exceed the weight, he can enter the lift and prompt the user to enter details of additional new passengers and this continues till the weight exceeds the Weight Limit.